# How do I generate random bulk tracking numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to generate multiple tracking numbers, and also how to make them like this.

UB5775XXXXXHK

So "XXXXX" above will be scrambled and become multiple tracking numbers like this

UB577594624HK
UB577573536HK
UB577593735HK

and so on until the number of limits we want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: Would you not at have some time have a duplicate tracking number when you're generating numbers in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use Math.random() * 10 to generate a random float
- Use Math.floor() or the quicker `~~` to floor the result (remove decimals)
- Concatenate your digits  using `+=`
- Insert them where needed using Template Literals (or again using concatenation `+`)

```js
const trackingNumber = (pr = "UB775", su = "HK") => {
  for(let i=0; i<5; i++) pr += ~~(Math.random() * 10);
  return pr + su;
};

console.log(trackingNumber()); 
console.log(trackingNumber());
console.log(trackingNumber());
console.log(trackingNumber());

// Example changing prefix and suffix:
console.log(trackingNumber("ZA001", "PD"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const input = "UB5775XXXXXHK";
const randomNumber = () => Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10); // To genrate a random number
const genrateTrackingNum = (str) => str.replace(/X/g, randomNumber); // To replace X with a random number


console.log(genrateTrackingNum(input));
console.log(genrateTrackingNum(input));
console.log(genrateTrackingNum(input));
console.log(genrateTrackingNum(input));
console.log(genrateTrackingNum(input));
```

▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬

#### Explanation:

---

The `randomNumber` function will generate a random number from `0` to `9`.

```js
const randomNumber = () => Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10);
```

---

The `genrateTrackingNum` function will replace every ***`X`*** in the input string (here `UB5775XXXXXHK`) with a random number.

```js
const genrateTrackingNum = (str) => str.replace(/X/g, randomNumber);
```

---